# jquery content slider needs autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this content slider and i need it to be like a slide show, i need auto play

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.poveznicaDiv').click(function(){
    var broj = $(this).attr('id');
    broj = broj.split('ca');
    broj = parseInt(broj[1]);       
    $('#maskaSadrzaja').animate({'left': '-'+ 500*(broj-1) +'px'}, 'slow');
});
});
```

ignore the id and class names they are on croatian :D

so this works just fine but i need autoplay for it

i tried this:

```
slideShow();

function slideShow(){
    var i = 0;
    $('#maskaSadrzaja').animate({'left': '-'+ 500*(i) +'px'}, 'slow');
    broj++;
    // alert(i);
    if(i>5){
        i=0;
    }   
    setTimeout(slideShow, 1000);
};
```

but this didnt work

how could i make it autoplay?

EDIT

so i tried something else
The divs with class .poveznicaDiv also have an id which is like poveznica1, poveznica2, and so on

So i tried adding a function wich clicks on them

Something like this:

```
i=1;
function autoplay() {
$('#poveznica'+i).click();
i++;
setTimeout(autoplay, 1000);
}
```

why doesnt this work?
I've put it in .ready and called the function (autoplay;). 
Help please

EDIT

My slider (and html and css) is almost identical to this one http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/12/lightest-jquery-content-slider-ever-made-380-bytes/

how could i make it rotate automaticly?

Comment: `i` is stuck at `0` and `broj` is not used

Answer (score 1):

You're not incrementing `i` in your code and you'll have to pass it to the function call as well since it's not a global variable.

```
var slideShow = function(i){
  $('#maskaSadrzaja').animate({
    'left': '-' + 500*(i) + 'px'
  }, 'slow');

  broj++;

  if(i>5){
    i=0;
  }   

  setTimeout(function(){
    slideShow(i+1);
  }, 1000);
};

slideShow(0);
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work.  I dont really need to increment broj do i? I tried putting it outside of .ready but it didnt work.

Comment: I don't know, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do without context. I was pointing out a rather obvious error in your code.

Comment: Yeah i know it was a stupid mistake but im new at js and jquery and practice makes perfect. Ok my slider is almost identical to this one http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/12/lightest-jquery-content-slider-ever-made-380-bytes/ how could i make it rotate automaticly?

Answer (score 0):

put it in Document.Ready , or like this for short

```
$(function() {       
var i = 0;
$('#maskaSadrzaja').animate({'left': '-'+ 500*(i) +'px'}, 'slow');
broj++;
// alert(i);
if(i>5){
    i=0;
}   
setTimeout(slideShow, 1000);
```

});

Comment: I just copied and pasted his code , to fire on load - "auto play"